# Error while trying to add multiple foreign keys to single table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to create a child table that constraints 3 foreign keys from the parent but I receive an error *1215: cannot add foreign key constraint*

parent table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `Availability` (
   `time_of_day` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `day_of_week` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`time_of_day`,`day_of_week`,`email`),
   KEY `email` (`email`),
   CONSTRAINT `Availability_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`email`) REFERENCES `service_provider` (`email_service_provider`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

child table (which I cant build due to error mentioned above):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1
(
  num_request INT NOT NULL,
  time_of_day VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  day_of_week VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (num_request),
    Foreign key (time_of_day) references Availability(time_of_day),
    Foreign key (day_of_week) references Availability(day_of_week),
    Foreign key (email) references Availability(email)
  );
```

Please show me what I'm doing wrong... Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're making a foreign key to a table with a composite primary key (i.e. a key of multiple columns), you should make the foreign key composite as well.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1
(
  num_request INT NOT NULL,
  time_of_day VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  day_of_week VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (num_request),
    Foreign key (time_of_day, day_of_week, email) references Availability(time_of_day, day_of_week, email)
)
```

The columns of the foreign key should match the columns of the primary or unique key they reference. They should have the same number of columns, in the same order.

What you tried to do was create three separate constraints of one column each.